# Submit button won't set

Tags: php, mysql, html

We can't get the delete "submit" button to set, otherwise it would work, we can't understand what part of the code is wrong.

Imagine a table row with a few columns, which contain data from a database in the td's

```
// While it goes through each row (which is selected from another SQL query above, but I won't bother pasting that)
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
// Variable is equal to the Request ID (e.g. 10)
$numb = $row['ReqID']; 

// Echo's the table td rows with each column name in the database
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td class='req' align='center'>".$row['ReqID']."</td>";
echo "<td class='req' align='center'>".$row['ModTitle']."</td>"; 
echo "<td class='req' align='center'>".$row['BuildingID']."</td>";
echo "<td class='req' align='center'>".$row['RoomID']."</td>";
echo "<td class='req' align='center'>".$row['Priority']."</td>";
echo "<td class='req' align='center'>".$row['W1']."</td>";
echo "<td class='req' align='center'>".$row['P1']."</td>";
// Delete button also in a td row, uses the variable "$numb" to set the button name
echo "<td class='req' align='center'><input type='submit' name='{$numb}' value='Delete'></td>";
echo "</tr>";

// If the delete button is pressed, delete the row (this query works, we tested it, but the button just doesn't set so it doesn't activate the SQL command)
if (isset($_POST[$numb])) {
$result2 = mysql_query("DELETE FROM Request WHERE ReqID = {$numb} LIMIT 1", $connection);
}
}
```

Comment: Why are you wrapping $numb with {}?

Comment: I assume the whole thing is wrapped around a `<form>` tag, right?

Comment: Not related to your question, but that code will display the deleted row after it was deleted... Is that the intended behavior?

Comment: Post the generated HTML.

Comment: @N.B. Wrapping a variable with {} within a string is perfectly valid.

Comment: @ceejayoz - did I say it was invalid? It's just useless. Hence the comment and not the answer.

Comment: I disagree that it's useless. I find it helps visibility for the variable, so it's easy to spot within the string. It's also necessary if you're referencing an array/object item, i.e. `{$something['item']}`.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `hidden` input to store the value:

somewhere above...

```
<form method="post" action="delete.php">
```

a little bit below...

```
echo "<td class='req' align='center'><input type='submit' name='submit' value='Delete'>";
echo '<input name="hello" type="hidden" value="$numb" /></td>';
...
$number = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["hello"]);
$result2 = mysql_query("DELETE FROM Request WHERE ReqID = ".$number." LIMIT 1", $connection);
```

at the bottom:

```
</form>
```

**Note:**

Your approach isn't safe enough. I can easily edit the DOM and give another value to the hidden field (or another name for the button) causing to delete other elements from the database. Keep in mind this.

Comment: Did you intend to `echo '<input ... value="' . $numb . '" />...'`?

Comment: Yeah right, just updated my code, but it's not better either. If it is an ID only, I can still delete other thing from the database as well... The approach itself is bad that I noted to him.